# SUBTOTAL but only where particular criteria is met (SUMIF/AVERAGEIF)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I currently use a SUBTOTAL function in Excel 365 to either sum, count or average a bunch of cells in a range. I was previously manually filtering the range so I was only totaling the rows I wanted, however the need has arisen to be able to look at several criteria at once.
i.e. in the example below, I was previously manually filtering range to only include "Apple" but now I need to be able to total "Apple", "Orange", "Banana" separately, at the same time.

The subtotal fields are used in graphs and I have a cell (F5) that houses a number corresponding to either SUM, COUNT or AVERAGE (9, 2 or 1) to use in the SUBTOTAL formulas in the "Summary table" which is linked to other functionality within the workbook and I need to still be able to retain that functionality.

Example of how my sheet is setup:

**Raw Data**

| Product Type | Sales QTY | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 4 | 1/9/21 |
| Orange | 3 | 6/9/21 |
| Banana | 2 | 10/9/21 |
| Apple | 6 | 14/9/21 |
| Orange | 6 | 20/9/21 |
| Apple | 5 | 29/9/21 |

The criteria I want to match is in Column 1 (Product Type) of the summary table.

Basically, I then want to be able to end up with the ability to display the data either as **totals**:

`$F$5 = 9`

for each line: `SUBTOTAL($F$5,SalesQTY)`

**Summary table**

| Product Type | Result (Sales Per Month) |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 15 |
| Orange | 9 |
| Banana | 2 |

Or as **averages**:

`$F$5 = 1`

for each line: `SUBTOTAL($F$5,SalesQTY)`

| Product Type | Result (Average QTY per Sale) |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 5 |
| Orange | 4.5 |
| Banana | 2 |

Or as a **count**:

`$F$5 = 2`

for each line: `SUBTOTAL($F$5,SalesQTY)`

| Product Type | Result (# Sales Transactions) |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 2 |
| Orange | 2 |
| Banana | 1 |

Is there some way I can combine SUMIF and also SUBTOTAL but also be able to retain the ability to flick between average, sum and count?

I have found a few questions and answers where SUMIF or SUMPRODUCT is used in place of SUBTOTAL, but I can't work out how to use those and still be able to flick between AVERAGE, SUM and COUNT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a nested if:
if ($F$5 = 1, use AVERAGEIF, if ($F$5 = 2, use COUNTIF,( if $F$5 = 9, use SUMIF, "")))

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if creating a pivot table can help you:
Select the table, and then go to *Insert tab>PivotTable>click OK*.
Please check the test screen recording. :
[image]

Comment: Hi, sorry I should have mentioned, the data is already in a pivot table. But due to the nature of the graphs, I need all the answers in just one column. The file is kind of a dashboard. So the graph data changes to reflect different things based on selections made. I can use another table for each that displays data based on an index, I was just trying to avoid the rework.